# Mongoid query by value or default value

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I've just updated one of my models with a boolean field. I've set a default value for the field to true. How can I query for this field in such a way that I get all documents with this field set to true or doesn't have this field (default value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find documents that *don't* have a particular key, you want to use [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists):

> **$exists**
>   *Syntax*: `{ field: { $exists: <boolean> } }`
>
> `$exists` selects the documents that contain the field if `<boolean>` is true. If `<boolean>` is false, the query only returns the documents that do not contain the field. `$exists` does match documents that contain the field that stores the `null` value.

So the existence check would look like:

```
Model.where(:field.exists => false)
Model.where(:field => { :$exists => false })
```

Note that the first `:field.exists` form becomes the second form before it gets sent to MongoDB; I mention this because you won't be able to use `:field` elsewhere in the query without using `$and` or `$or` to combine the clauses: the `:field.exists` expansion can lead to keys in the query Hash overwriting each other. You won't have this problem here but a reminder can't hurt.

Looking for `true` is easy:

```
Model.where(:field => true)
```

You want either one so combine them with [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or):

```
Model.where(:$or => [
  { :field.exists => false },
  { :field        => true  }
])
```

If `:field` might be there but have a `null` value then you could use `{ :field => nil }` to match documents where `:field` is `null` **or** not there at all:

```
Model.where(:$or => [
  { :field => null  },
  { :field => true  }
])
# or
Model.where(:field.in => [ null, true ]) # This is probably the one you want
```

There's also `{ :field => { :$type => 10 } }` if you're looking for things that are there **and** explicitly `null`. Now might be a good time for a quick review of the  MongoDB FAQ:

> [**How do I query for fields that contain null values?**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls)