# Update specific record model on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, migration, mongoid

I updated my user model locally, and pushed it to my heroku environment.

However now I'm running into the issue where an old user doesn't have the field that all new users have.

From the `heroku console` how do I specifically add a field to this single user who is missing a necessary field? I'm using `mongoid` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options:

1. If you don't need to query on this new field then just add a `:default => whatever` value to the field. That will set the default value for new instances and supply the default value to existing models that don't have the field.
2. If you do need to query on this field and you want to add a default value to all existing documents that don't have it, then you can use an [`:$exists` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145525/479863) to find them and `update_all` to fix them:

   ```
   M.where(:missing_field.exists => false).update_all(:missing_field => desired_value)
   ```

   That will do a `:$set => { :missing_field => desired_value }` update behind the scenes so it will only modify the `:missing_field`.
3. If there's just one and you know which one it is then just grab it, update the value, and save it:

   ```
   m = M.find(known_id)
   m.missing_value = desired_value
   m.save
   ```
4. If you want to talk straight to the database then use `find` and `update_all` with the collection:

   ```
   M.collection.find(:missing_field => { :$exists => false }).update_all(:$set => { :missing_field => desired_value })
   M.collection.find(:_id => known_id).update(:$set => { :missing_field => desired_value })
   ```